# How to remove index varchar_pattern_ops in a django (1.8) migration?

Tags: django, postgresql, migration, django-migrations, database-indexes

When creating a model with a `models.varchar(...)` field, a `varchar_pattern_ops` index is being created.

This is the table generated in postgresql

```
              Table "public.logger_btilog"
      Column      |           Type           | Modifiers 
------------------+--------------------------+-----------
 md5hash          | text                     | 
 id               | integer                  | not null
Indexes:
    "logger_btilog_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "logger_btilog_md5hash_6454d7bb20588b61_like" btree (md5hash varchar_pattern_ops)
```

I want to remove that `varchar_pattern_ops` index in a migration, and add a hash index in that field.

I tried doing this:

```
# models.py
class Btilog(models.Model):
    md5hash = models.TextField(db_index=False)
    [...]
```

And in migration also force adding `db_field=False`

```
# 0013_migration.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('logger', '0014_btilog_id'),
    ]

    operations = [
        # this should remove all indexes for md5hash, but it does not work
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='btilog',
            name='md5hash',
            field=models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, db_index=False),
        ),
        migrations.RunSQL(
            "create index logger_btilog_md5hash_hashindex on logger_btilog using hash(md5hash);",
            "drop index logger_btilog_md5hash_hashindex;"
        ),
]
```

After running the migrations, this are the indexes in the database

```
                              relation                              |  size   
--------------------------------------------------------------------+---------
 public.logger_btilog                                               | 7185 MB
 public.logger_btilog_md5hash_6454d7bb20588b61_like                 | 1442 MB
 public.logger_btilog_md5hash_hashindex                             | 1024 MB
 public.logger_btilog_pkey                                          | 548 MB
```

Note that `public.logger_btilog_md5hash_6454d7bb20588b61_like` is the index I want to delete. This index is being added automatically by django, see [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12234)

More info on that index

```
vtfx=# \d logger_btilog_md5hash_6454d7bb20588b61_like
Index "public.logger_btilog_md5hash_6454d7bb20588b61_like"
 Column  | Type | Definition 
---------+------+------------
 md5hash | text | md5hash
btree, for table "public.logger_btilog"
```

Footnote: I'm not confused about the usage of a hash index, I only want to do `=` (strictrly equal) `where` searches in `md5hash` field, then (casually) a `hash` index would be the fastest and will occupy less space than a `btree` index (django's default)

Comment: You know hash indexes aren't crash-safe and aren't replicated, right?

Comment: No I didn't... Thanks for pointing that out, I'll read more on that. Nevertheless, the problem is the other index deletion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **Answer update notice:**
>
> - django < 1.11: Use this answer
> - django >= 1.11: Use @Cesar Canassa's answer

Ok, I found some info here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/db/backends/base/schema/#BaseDatabaseSchemaEditor.alter_field

And made a manual `RunPython` migration to delete the `varchar_pattern_ops` index using the `SchemaEditor`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations


import re
def drop_md5hash_varchar_pattern_ops_index(apps, schemaEditor):
    # code based on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/db/backends/base/schema/#BaseDatabaseSchemaEditor.alter_field
    model = apps.get_model("logger", "Btilog")
    index_names = schemaEditor._constraint_names(model, index=True)
    for index_name in index_names:
        if re.search('logger_btilog_md5hash_.+_like', index_name):
            print 'dropping index {}'.format(index_name)
            schemaEditor.execute(schemaEditor._delete_constraint_sql(schemaEditor.sql_delete_index, model, index_name))


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('logger', '0012_auto_20150529_1745'),
    ]

    operations = [
        # Remove the annoying index using a hack
        migrations.RunPython(
            drop_md5hash_varchar_pattern_ops_index
        ),
    ]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can avoid the creation of the `varchar_pattern_ops` "LIKE" index altogether by using the new [Model Meta indexes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#indexes) option that was added in Django 1.11. For example, instead of writing your Model like this:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.CharField(max_length=64, db_index=True)
```

You need to set the index with the Model Meta option:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['my_field'])
        ]
```

By doing so, Django will not create the duplicated index.

Comment: Do you have a trick to do not create the duplicate index when the field has the unique flag set ? Even if I add db_index=False explicitly, it is creating 3 indexes: the 2 original ones + the new one

Comment: Same issue with foreign key to a table with string pk.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Django **3.0.11** and I had same problem. I don't want *_like* index for primary key since it's used only for joins and exact matching.

Defining index manually won't help if field is primary_key. So I came up with hacky solution similar to first answer.

```py
from django.db import migrations, models


def drop_pattern_ops_index(schema_editor, model, field):
    indexes = schema_editor._model_indexes_sql(model)
    for index in indexes:
        columns = index.parts["columns"].columns
        opclasses = index.parts["columns"].opclasses
        if field in columns and len(columns) == 1:
            # Django uses varchar_pattern_ops or text_pattern_ops
            if "pattern_ops" in opclasses[0]:
                drop_sql = schema_editor._delete_index_sql(
                    model, str(index.parts["name"]).strip('"')
                )
                # Indexes creation is always deferred in migration 
                # so we have to execute remove at the end
                schema_editor.deferred_sql.extend([drop_sql])
                break


def drop_extra_indexes(apps, schema_editor):
    model = apps.get_model("com_erp", "TestModel")
    drop_pattern_ops_index(schema_editor, model, "code")


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name="TestModel",
            fields=[
                ("code", models.TextField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ("name", models.TextField()),
            ],
            options={"db_table": "test_table",},
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(drop_extra_indexes, migrations.RunPython.noop),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementing @Cesar Canassa's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50926644/10451701) for the cases of a unique field.

To avoid the duplicated indexes you have to drop the `unique=True` in the field and add this constraint in the Meta class:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
my_field = models.CharField(max_length=64)
my_unique_field = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(
            name='unique_field_constraint',
            fields=['my_unique_field']
        ),
    indexes = [
        models.Index(fields=['my_field'])
    ]
```